# Transfer file from Google Drive to Mediafire

Tags: download, file-transfer, bittorrent, google-drive, upload

Is there any way to transfer a file from Google Drive to Mediafire?

I want to download a file from torrent. When using Boxopus I can't download this file directly (I get an HTTP error). So I saved it to Google Drive but I can't download the file with download manager in Ubuntu. For that reason I want to transfer this file to Mediafire.

My Internet speed is very slow so I can't download with torrent, download with single connection and should download with a download manager.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your  [question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) is somewhat difficult to understand.  Please edit it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary you transfer the file to MediaFire.

You can use [**`Grive`**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/grive/) - Google Drive client for Linux, It allows synchronize your Google Drive files with a directory on your local storage from the command-line.

Follow these steps to install:

- Add the Grive Tools [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/grive-tools) to your software sources and install Grive Tools. Open a terminal window and enter:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install grive-tools
  ```
- Using Grive:

  1. Grive will *download/upload* new or changed files from the directory you run it so firstly, create a new folder, let's call it `grive`, in your home directory:

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/grive
     ```
  2. Next, navigate using the terminal into the newly created `grive` folder:

     ```
     cd ~/grive
     ```
  3. The first time you run Grive, you must use the `-a` argument to grant it permission to access your Google Drive:

     ```
     grive -a
     ```

After running the command above, an *URL* should be displayed in the terminal - copy this *URL* and paste it in a web browser. In the newly loaded page, you'll be asked to give Grive permission to access your Google Drive and after clicking **Allow access**, an authentication code will be displayed - copy this code and paste it in the terminal where you ran Grive.

That's it. Now each time you want to sync Google Drive with your local `grive` folder, navigate to the `grive` folder (*step 2*) and run `grive` (this time without `-a` since you've already authenticated Grive with Google Drive).

<sub>[**Source¹**](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html)</sub>
<sub>[**Source²**](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OffCloud](https://offcloud.com) to download torrent file directly to your Google Drive. Or to other cloud service. 
*It's a paid service but you can try it for free for up to 3 torrents*

And you can use [MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com) to transfert from Google Drive to Mediafire (or to other cloud services) and vice versa.
*It's a paid service too but you can use it for free for up to 2TB.*